# Different output of binary operations on the same machine

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, c, binary

Executing this JavaScript code in Safari

```
// expected output - array containing 32 bit words
b = "a";
    var a = Array((b.length+3) >> 2);
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) a[i>>2] |= (b.charCodeAt(i) << (24-(i & 3)*8));
```

and this (Objective-)C code in iOS Simulator

```
    int array[((@"a".length + 3) >> 2)];

for (int i = 0; i < @"a".length; i++) {
    int c = (int) [@"a" characterAtIndex:i];
    array[i>>2] |= (c << (24-((i & 3)*8)));

}
```

gives me different output - consecutively (JavaScript) 1627389952 and (Objective-C) 1627748484.

Since the first four digits are always the same I think that the error is connected with precision but I cannot spot the issue.

**EDIT**

Sorry for this lack of attention and thank you very much (@Joni and all of you guys). You were right that the array in C code is fullfilled with some random values. I solved the issue setting all elements in the array to zero:

```
memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
```

**If anyone is curious the C code looks like this now:**

```
int array[((@"a".length + 3) >> 2)];

memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));

for (int i = 0; i < @"a".length; i++) {
    int c = (int) [@"a" characterAtIndex:i];
    array[i>>2] |= (c << (24-((i & 3)*8)));

}
```

Comment: In javascript, every number is a float. This might result in precision issues, as you say.

Comment: Well in this case the JavaScript answer is the correct one. Are arrays in Objective-C implicitly initialized with zeros?

Comment: Also in JavaScript there's no point in "allocating" an array with the "Array" constructor (usually).

Comment: @Pointy Semantically no, but it will be optimized to real allocation by V8 and Spidermonkey. Additionally if you initialize values to `0` instead of constantly doing out of bounds access, you should get a huge speed boost because that can be expressed in very low level code whereas undefined conversion on out of bounds gets into the messy convoluted javascript semantics.

Comment: @Esailija wow I did not know that; I know that it used to have an effect a long time ago, but I didn't realize the newer VMs take advantage of pre-allocation. (In IE6, passing a huge number to the Array constructor could result in an out-of-memory issue I think. Or maybe it was old, old Mozilla.)

Comment: @Pointy in Chrome the limit is 100k: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/abfa9f17410a2a84c2ac3364e0288f4a8311b9b1/src/objects.h#L2411 I cannot find the same for spidermonkey

Comment: @Pointy although you can just create many arrays of 99999 to crash Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/SDCMF/ :P so I guess it's not that different from IE6 in that regard. And because often multiple tabs share same process then this could be quite evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the array to zeros in objective c, so it may have some random garbage to start with.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how Objective-c initializes arrays but in javascript 
they are not initialized to anything (in fact, the indices don't even exist), so take care of that at least:

```
var b = "a";
var a = Array((b.length + 3) >> 2);
for( var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; ++i ) {
    a[i] = 0; //initialize a values to 0
}
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    a[i >> 2] |= (b.charCodeAt(i) << (24 - (i & 3) * 8));
}
```

Secondly, this effectively should calculate `97 << 24`, for which the correct
answer is `1627389952`, so the Objective-C result is wrong. Probably because
the array values are not initialized to 0?

Comment: Well you're right about JavaScript array values being `undefined`, but in an integer math expression they'll be turned into zeros. Still flaky however.

Comment: @Pointy well the array values are not `undefined` - `undefined` value is returned from non-existing property access. Then it probably goes to `NaN` and again `NaN` is converted to `0` because 32-bit ints cannot do NaN... so yea I guess it is all the same :D

Comment: Well yes, right. It's weird that `NaN` propagates through floating point operations but goes away in integer operations. I understand why that makes sense internally but it doesn't make things any easier  for new programmers :/